# Track Firebase Push notification for web in console

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

Is there any way to track the count of successfully sent push notifications in FCM ? I can see the messages sent using Firebase console but i need to track the number of messages sent via web app to the devices.

I have tried the same using onMessaging event of firebase, tried sending direct hit for google analytics as well from service worker but without any success.

```
return fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', {
  method: 'post',
  body: payloadString
})
```

Also tried logEvent using following -

```
 const analytics = firebase.analytics();
  logEvent(analytics, 'web_notification', {action : 'send'});
```

No event is getting saved in firebase console. Is there any way I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can check those data in [BigQuery export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export). Just link your Firebase app to BigQuery. From there, you can [query the messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#what-data-exported) that were successfully sent.